# Salesforce CPQ Custom Template Content (Quote Templates) not showing field value from custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller, cpq, quote-template

I just created a simple quote template. With 1 Template Section. I have assigned that section with a Custom Template content that references a visualforce page I created.

Visualforce page,

```
<apex:page contentType="text/xml" controller="CustomQuoteController" showHeader="false">
    <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.SBQQ__BillingName__c}"></apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

CustomQuoteController,

```
public class CustomQuoteController{

       private final SBQQ__Quote__c currentQuote;
       private SBQQ__QuoteLine__c[] currentQuoteLineList;

       public CustomQuoteController(){
            SBQQ__Quote__c[] currentQuoteList = [SELECT Id, SBQQ__BillingName__c 
            FROM SBQQ__Quote__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

            if(currentQuoteList.size() > 0){
                 currentQuote = currentQuoteList[0]; 
            }
       }

       public SBQQ__Quote__c  getQuote(){
             return currentQuote;
       }


       public SBQQ__QuoteLine__c[] getQuoteLines(){

               if(currentQuote != null){
                     currentQuoteLineList = [SELECT id, SBQQ__ProductCode__c 
                     FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c WHERE SBQQ__Quote__r.id = :currentQuote.id];
               }

               return currentQuoteLineList;
       }
}
```

SBQQ__BillingName__c name doesn't display when preview quote template document. It's just blank. Anyone know why ? What am I missing ? Do I have to change something ?

When I remove contentType="text/xml" and preview the visualforce page it shows the SBQQ__BillingName__c  value.

This all also in Salesforce CPQ.

How to make it work and show up in quote document ?

Comment: Did you find what was an issue?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, via debugging, a couple of months back regarding this issue. For Salesforce CPQ Quote Template, ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters() doesn't have a 'id' parameter. It has a 'qid' parameter.

So this,

```
SBQQ__Quote__c[] currentQuoteList = [SELECT Id, SBQQ__BillingName__c 
            FROM SBQQ__Quote__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
```

needs to be changed to,

```
SBQQ__Quote__c[] currentQuoteList = [SELECT Id, SBQQ__BillingName__c 
            FROM SBQQ__Quote__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('qid')];
```

Here are parameters returned by ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters() for Salesforce CPQ Quote Templates,

[image]